# I want to manage toolbar text while using swiping tabs

Tags: android

[image]

I have five tabs in a Activity which can swipe. While swiping the tabs toolbar text need to change accordingly. For that I used Interface calling that method from Fragment to Activity, but its not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it by using the bellow way..

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position == 0) {
                toobar.setTitle("one");
            } else if (position == 1) {
                toobar.setTitle("two");

            } else if (position == 2) {
                toobar.setTitle("three");
            } else if (position == 3) {
                toobar.setTitle("four");
            } else if (position == 4) {
                toobar.setTitle("five");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to change the title of your toolbar according to the tab selected. For this purpose you can try using `android-support-design-library`:

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{


    TabLayout tabs;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabsPagerAdapter adapter;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    CharSequence Titles[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    int Numboftabs = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabs.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    tabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
 @Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    switch(tab.getPosition()) {

        case 0:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            toolbar.setTitle("Your Title one");
            break;
        case 1:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            toolbar.setTitle("Your Title two");
            break;
        case 2:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            toolbar.setTitle("Your title three");
            break;
        default:

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            toolbar.setTitle("Your APP NAME");
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
}
```